Git Status failing on a Large Repo only on Windows side of a NFS
I'm having a git error only on the Windows side of a Linux NFS. I'm trying to resolve this error and have some control of my Git repository in Windows.
This is the error I'm seeing on Windows command line:
C:\repo_location\repo> git status

Refresh index:100% (10000/10000), done
fatal: bad object HEAD
fatal: 'git status --porcelain=2' failed in submodule patha/a
fatal: 'git status --porcelain=2' failed in submodule pathb/b
fatal: 'git status --porcelain=2' failed in submodule pathc/c

I have tested git status on the Linux server on the other side of the NFS which works.
As debug step I confirmed my install on Windows works on other smaller repos.
I have tried reinitializing (git init) of my submodules in Windows as recommended in other posts on stack overflow with somewhat similar issues on this forum.
My immediate thoughts are that this issue is related to path length limits in Windows or LF/CRLF issues. Again the repo I'm working on is very large. Urgh Windows, and how I am cursed to have to use it professionally.

Sharing a Git repository over a network file system has problems, even worse when it's cross-platform. I don't know what might be causing your particular problem, but you're better off treating it as a remote repository.
